# Java get image from webcam and send over socket

Tags: java, sockets, memory, memory-management, webcam

I'm using `Webcam capture API` by sarxos http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/

I write this code to continuously get image from webcam and send it through socket to server.

Client code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 54339);
    ObjectOutputStream sender = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    Webcam wCam = Webcam.getDefault();
    wCam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());
    wCam.open();
    while (true)
    {
        sender.writeObject(new ImageIcon(wCam.getImage()));
    }
}
```

Server code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(54339);
    Socket socket = server.accept();

    ObjectInputStream rcv = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    while (true)
    {
        rcv.readObject();
        System.out.println("receive");
    }
}
```

But then after about 2 - 3 minutes, my client run out of memory and stuck because it takes too much RAM.

I think it's because of this line `new ImageIcon(wCam.getImage())` but I don't know how to fix it.

I've tried `sender.flush()` but it's not work

Answer (score 2):

Basically `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` and `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` maintain a table of **`hard`** `references` to the objects they have sent/received. When an object is **resent** by `ObjectOutputStream`, only a handle to the object is sent, while `ObjectInputStream` translates the received handle to the reference of the previously received object. This feature reduces bandwidth and memory usage but only in programs where objects are regularly re-sent. Since  `ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream` hard reference these objects, `Garbage Collector` can't collect them and eventually these objects became a memory leak.

To avoid this, Java offers `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()` and `ObjectInputStream.readUnshared()` methods but those methods **also have a known memory leak** issue, check [JDK-6525563 : Memory leak in ObjectOutputStream](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6525563) for more info about that issue.

So you have 2 options;

1. Use `read/writeUnshared()` instead of `read/writeObject()` and call `ObjectOutputStream`'s `reset()` method every once in a while for to free up the memory leaked by `ObjectOutputStream`,
2. Avoid using `ObjectInput/OutputStream`. You can read/write `BufferedImage` with `DataInput/OutputStream` like this;

Writing:

```
try (DataOutputStream sender = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new Socket("127.0.0.1", 54339).getOutputStream()))) //never use DataStreams without buffering, too slow
{
    while (true)
    {
        BufferedImage frame = wCam.getImage(); //get frame from webcam
        int frameWidth = frame.getWidth();
        int frameHeight = frame.getHeight();

        sender.writeInt(frameWidth); //write image with
        sender.writeInt(frameHeight); //write image height

        int[] pixelData = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];
        frame.getRGB(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, pixelData, 0, frameWidth);

        for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.length; i++)
        {
            sender.writeInt(pixelData[i]); //write pixel data
        }
    }
}
```

Reading:

```
try (DataInputStream rcv = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()))) //never use DataStreams without buffering, too slow
{

    while (true)
    {
        int frameWidth = rcv.readInt(); //read image with
        int frameHeight = rcv.readInt(); //read image height

        int[] pixelData = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];
        for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.length; i++)
        {
            pixelData[i] = rcv.readInt(); //read pixel data
        }

        BufferedImage frame = new BufferedImage(frameWidth, frameHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); //create immage
        frame.setRGB(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, pixelData, 0, frameWidth);  //set pixel data

        //do whatever you want with frame
    }
}
```

Also my implementation of method 2 with displaying received image on server;

`Server.java`:

```
public class Server
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(54339);
        Socket socket = server.accept();

        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.setSize(800, 600);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        ImageDisplayPanel imageDisplayPanel = new ImageDisplayPanel();
        jframe.add(imageDisplayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jframe.setVisible(true);

        try (DataInputStream rcv = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream())))
        {

            while (true)
            {
                int frameWidth = rcv.readInt();
                int frameHeight = rcv.readInt();

                int[] pixelData = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];

                for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.length; i++)
                {
                    pixelData[i] = rcv.readInt();
                }

                BufferedImage frame = new BufferedImage(frameWidth, frameHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                frame.setRGB(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, pixelData, 0, frameWidth);

                imageDisplayPanel.setBackground(frame);
            }
        }
    }


    private static class ImageDisplayPanel extends JPanel
    {
        private static final Object BACKGROUND_LOCK = new Object();
        private BufferedImage background = null;

        public ImageDisplayPanel () throws HeadlessException
        {
            this.setDoubleBuffered(true); //to avoid flicker
        }

        public void setBackground (Image newBackground)
        {
            synchronized (BACKGROUND_LOCK)
            {
                if (background == null)
                {
                    background = new BufferedImage(newBackground.getWidth(null), newBackground.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                }
                else if (background.getWidth() != newBackground.getWidth(null) || background.getHeight() != newBackground.getHeight(null))
                {
                    background.flush();//flush old resources first
                    background = new BufferedImage(newBackground.getWidth(null), newBackground.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                }
                Graphics graphics = background.createGraphics();
                graphics.drawImage(newBackground, 0, 0, null);
            }
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void paint (Graphics g)
        {
            super.paint(g);
            synchronized (BACKGROUND_LOCK)
            {
                if (background != null)
                {
                    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Client.java` :

```
public class Client
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Webcam wCam = null;
        try (DataOutputStream sender = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new Socket("127.0.0.1", 54339).getOutputStream())))
        {

            wCam = Webcam.getDefault();
            wCam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());
            wCam.open();
            while (true)
            {
                BufferedImage frame = wCam.getImage(); //get frame from webcam

                int frameWidth = frame.getWidth();
                int frameHeight = frame.getHeight();

                sender.writeInt(frameWidth);
                sender.writeInt(frameHeight);

                int[] pixelData = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];
                frame.getRGB(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, pixelData, 0, frameWidth);

                for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.length; i++)
                {
                    sender.writeInt(pixelData[i]);
                }
            }
        } finally
        {
            //release resources used by library
            if (wCam != null)
            {
                wCam.close();
            }
            Webcam.shutdown();
        }

    }
}
```